# Find last occurrence of a whitespace character before an offset?

Tags: php

Suppose I have a string, "The quick brown fox" and I want to find the last occurence of a whitespace character on or before index 13:

```
01234567890123456789
The quick brown fox
         ^
```

How would I do that? I'd like to use a reverse regex search for `\s` but I don't think PHP supports searching backwards before an offset. Is there another way to do this efficiently?

Comment: Is there a more static identifier? I.e. Presume it wont always be that text, or a space between "quick" and "brown" or index 13.

Comment: That's correct. The string and the index are variables. "Whitespace characters" however is fixed (space, newline, tab, etc)

Comment: I don't think so, maybe this is for Code Review

Answer (score 2):

```
$string='the quick brown fox';
$ind=13;

function findWS($string,$ind)
{
   $string=substr($string,0,$ind+1);   
   preg_match('/\s*[^\s]+$/',$string,$match,PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE );
   if(isset($match[0][1])) return $match[0][1]; else return -1; 
}

$v=findWS($string,$ind);

echo $v;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this will work as long as the `$pattern` matches only one character:

```
function rePosRev($subject, $pattern, $offset=null) {
    if($offset === null) $offset = strlen($subject);
    $search_str = strrev(substr($subject, 0, $offset));
    if(preg_match($pattern, $search_str, $m, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE)) {
        return $offset - $m[0][1] - 1;
    }
    return false;
}

echo rePosRev("The quick brown fox", '~\s~', 13); // 9
```

[ideone](http://ideone.com/1wEeci)

Comment: @James Some basic tests, yes. I've included the output and a link to where you can run it...